# Replace each character of matched text with certain text

Tags: regex, pcre

I use `PCRE` regex and I have a problem with replacing each word of the matched text.

I use this pattern to match the desired text with grouping:

```
(?<=^|[_\-/:]\w)(\w+?)(?=\w[_\-/:]|$)
```

And the sample text is this:

> `yVOdbtnRWSkpgi0iDWeRtyynyREV7yVKyNuJmsFmpSPtnlXaLb/Ik4zuyJFwqRWCGeIRp7m3Cef9kSjvCIrFG4iaweaB49WecZoNP8CTta79kVXpAcIVohHnsLcJ5+`

I would like to convert all characters of grouped match `($1)` to `?i`:

> `yV?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?iLb/Ik?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?i?iJ5+`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to search:

```sh
~(?<=[^+/_-]\w)\w(?=\w[^+/_-])~
```

and replace using:

```
?i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1npGhT/1)

**Code:**

```
$repl = preg_replace('~(?<=[^+/_-]\w)\w(?=\w[^+/_-])~', '?i', $str);
```

**RegEx Demo**

- `(?<=[^+/_-]\w)`: Positive lookbehind to assert that we have a character that is not a `+`, `/`, `_` and `-` followed by a word character followed by at **previous position**
- `\w`: Match a word character
- `(?=\w[^+/_-])`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a word character followed by a character that is not a `+`, `/`, `_` and `-` **ahead**

Comment: May I know why did you remove acceptance mark from my answer? Is it not working suddenly?

Comment: Unfortunately, nah

Comment: My regex demo still shows your expected output, what changed?

Comment: It matches **_** also but i don't want to match it

Comment: You're pattern In question also matches underscore, please update the question of requirements have changed

Comment: If you want to leave `_` out then use `(?<=[^+/_-]\w)[a-zA-Z0-9](?=\w[^+/_-])`

Comment: Thanks a lot and excuse me for the lately answer